# How to read from two files in the same time shell

Tags: file, shell, unix, printing

I have two files,

```
A

john 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Ely 10 9 9 9 9 9 9
Maria 3 5 7 9 2 1 4
Rox 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

B 
john 7.5
Ely 4.5
Maria 3,7
Rox 8.5
```

What i want to do is create another file with only the persons who have in file A their average greater or equal with the 8.5 and in B their mark also greater or equal to 8.5, so in my example the C file would contain only Rox because only she fulfil the criteria.

I have this

```
#shell program
echo "Fiserul are numele $1"
filename=$1
filename2=$2
echo "">temp.txt
touch results
compara="8.5"
cat $filename | while read -r line
do
    nota=0
    media=0
    echo " $line"
    rem=$( echo "$line"| cut -f 2- -d ' ')
    for word in $rem 
    do
        echo "$word"
        nota=$(($nota+$word))
        echo "Nota=$nota"
    done
    media=$(($nota / 7))
    if [ "$(echo $media '>=' $compara | bc -l)" -eq 1 ];
    then 
        nume=$( echo "$line"| cut -f 1 -d ' ')
        echo "$nume $media" >> temp.txt
    fi
    echo "Media : $media"
done
cat $filename2 | while read -r line
do
```

so I have in the temp.txt files the persons who fulfil the criteria for file A but my question is how can i compare them with the persons from filename2 and create "results" from them ?
I've tried with two while loops but i get an error, could someone please help ? 
Thanks!

Comment: This would be much easier to do in awk, but I don't have time to sketch it out for you. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @shellter - award for the worst answer ever!  congratulations! 

Q:"How do I get to Chicago by bike?"  
A: "Well it would be much easier for me to drive you there because I have a really nice car and I'm also very smart, but sorry I don't have time.  Good luck!"

Comment: @user3133172, you'll note that the comment was posed as a **comment**, not an answer. Also, awk **is** the better tool for the OP's real question -- having support for proper floating-point math means all the hackery with `bc` would be unnecessary. Likewise all the subprocesses invoking cut and similar tools (though they aren't necessary in bash either, but are rather evidence of the OP not knowing the available native string-manipulation tools and resorting to out-of-process ones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *really* want to read two files at the same time (which doesn't appear to be your actual question -- `join` is indeed the right tool for what you're doing), you can open them on different FDs:

```
while IFS= read -r -u 4 line1 && IFS= read -r -u 5 line2; do
  echo "Line from first file: $line1"
  echo "Line from second file: $line2"
done 4<file1 5<file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `join` command to combine A and B into a single file C:

```
$ join A.txt B.txt
john 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7.5
Ely 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 4.5
Maria 3 5 7 9 2 1 4 3,7
Rox 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 8.5
```

It should be simple to modify your current script to process the data in this form.