# I have 2 files, file1 have strings & file2 have lines. need to replace first string from file1 within a line from file2 if file2 line contains xxxxx

Tags: shell

Following is the sample file1 and file2 with the script. Not sure where is the issue. please help.

File1

```
first line text xxxxx
second line xxxxx some more text
third line without to replace anything
line third xxxxx
```

File2

```
first value
second value
some third value
```

Script

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r value1
do
    while read -r value2
    do
        if [[ "$value1" != *"xxxxx"* ]]
            then
            echo $value1
            continue
        else
            echo $value1 | sed "s/xxxxx/$value2/"
            break
        fi
    done <file2
done <file1
```

Expected output:

```
first line text first value
second line second value some more text
third line without to replace anything
line third line third
```

but getting the following

`first line text first value
second line first value some more text
third line without to replace anything
third line without to replace anything
third line without to replace anything
line third first value`

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question, but in your script, for every line in *file1*, the inner loop reads *file2* from the beginning, until it breaks out. This is obviously, what this script is supposed to do. So, if it reads the first line only from line 2, it means that the *if* condition is already *false* for this first line.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. updated the details in my question for what I am looking and what I am getting.

Comment: In this case, you need to process the two files in parallel, not restarting *file2* from the beginning every time.  BTW, why do you want to implement this in Posix shell, when there are so many languages are available where this is easier to do?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642981/how-to-read-from-two-files-in-the-same-time-shell) on how to read from two files.